# Google Maps API - Removing All Map Labels with Exceptions

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using this to remove all map labels from a Google Map:

```
var customStyled = [
{
featureType: "all",
elementType: "labels",
stylers: [
{ visibility: "off" }
]
}
];
map.set('styles',customStyled);
```

Is there a way to show ONLY country names, for example? Or ONLY country name and state name? If not, does anyone know where to find a complete list of ALL label element names so that I can disable all of them except for the ones I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Styling wizard of Google Maps API that shows all available options and allows to generate custom style.

https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

You can set visibility on country, province, locality, etc. labels as shown in my screenshot

[image]

The resulting style might be something like

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.country",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
    "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
    "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
    "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
    "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.province",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
    "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know this tool existed. It makes it a lot easier.

Comment: Happy to help, if this answer solves your issue, please accept it.